# No network specified. Cannot determine current network

Tags: truffle

How to solve the following problem?

```
 $ truffle migrate
    Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.
        at Object.detect (C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\environment.js:31:1)
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-core\lib\commands\migrate.js:91:1
        at finished (C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-workflow-compile\index.js:53:1)
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\index.js:314:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:158:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:3888:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:473:1
        at replenish (C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:1006:1)
        at iterateeCallback (C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:995:1)
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:969:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:3885:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:154:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:1140:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:473:1
        at iteratorCallback (C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:1064:1)
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:969:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\async\dist\async.js:1137:1
        at C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-compile\profiler.js:133:1
        at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

Comment: Share truffle.js

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify a network in your truffle.js file.
you should have something like :

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    my_ganache: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*"  
    }
  }
};
```

then use `--network my_ganache` in all your commands. EXP:

```
truffle migrate --network my_ganache
```

of course you should have in this case ganache running under port 7545